# Pass list variable to JSON template in terraform

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, templates, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a cloudwatch dashboard in terraform that would be configurable via variables. I realize that dashboard body is a JSON string, so basic interpolation (like "region" property below) works. But with something like "metrics" I need to pass a list - and terraform throws "invalid interpolation" error. Is there a way to have configurable template where I can pass complex variables?

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "dashboard" {
  dashboard_name = "dashboard"

  dashboard_body = <<EOF
  {
    "widgets": [
      {
        "type": "metric",
        "width": 12,
        "properties": {
          "metrics": ${local.database_metrics},
          "region": "${var.aws_region}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform has a [jsonencode function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. So basically I can create an entire structure in a variable and then `jsonencode` it. But majority of the template is static, unchanging, there're only a few moving parts. Is there a way to load a static template and just substitute variables with values?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter yes there is a `templatefile` function that does exactly what you just described: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html

Comment: I look into this, but unless I misunderstood it supports the same type of string interpolation like regular terraform code. Which means I cannot pass a list or a map as a variable. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You would pass a `jsonencode(list)` or `jsonencode(map)` as your variables, since you are rendering JSON.

Comment: If you _do_ intend to split this out into a separate file with `templatefile`, please note [the advice in the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template) about using a single call to `jsonencode` to produce the entire structure at once, rather than trying to produce JSON by string concatenation.